# join with pivot table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables that like t1 and t2.
t1

```
ID                          class name
--                          -----------
1                            basket weaving
2                            Underwater Basketing

t2
ID                            POS     DAYS
--                            ----    -----
1                              1      M
1                              2      T
1                              3      W
1                              4     TH
1                              5      F
2                              1      M
2                              2      W
2                              3      F
```

I want to get the following output from both tables.

```
1                             class                  DAYS
--                            -----                  -----
1                             BASKET WEAVING         MTWTHF
2                             Underwater basketing   MWF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query1**

```
SELECT ID, [class name], STUFF(List, 1 ,2, '') [DAYS]
    FROM Table1 T1 CROSS APPLY 
                            (
                            SELECT ', ' + [DAYS] [text()]
                            FROM Table2
                            WHERE ID = T1.ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T2(List)
```

**RESULT**

```
ID                            class name             DAYS
--                            -----                  -----
1                             BASKET WEAVING         M,T,W,TH,F
2                             Underwater basketing   M,W,F
```

It Will give you a Comma delimited List of the days if you want with out commas you can use the following
**Query2**

```
SELECT ID, [class name], List [DAYS]
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS APPLY 
                        (
                        SELECT  [DAYS] [text()]
                        FROM Table2
                        WHERE ID = T1.ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ) T2(List)
```

**RESULT**

```
ID                            class name             DAYS
--                            -----                  -----
1                             BASKET WEAVING         MTWTHF
2                             Underwater basketing   MWF
```

**Query3**

```
SELECT ID, [class name], STUFF(List, 1 ,2, '') [DAYS], STUFF(T3.Rooms, 1 ,2, '') [Rooms]
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS APPLY 
                            (
                            SELECT ', ' + [DAYS] [text()]
                            FROM Table2
                            WHERE ID = T1.ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ) T2(List)
               CROSS APPLY 
                        (
                        SELECT '/' + Rooms [text()]
                        FROM Table2
                        WHERE ID = T1.ID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ) T3(Rooms)
```

you can add another column by doing something like this .....

Comment: Can this be done to return more.  For example if I added a fourth column to t2 called rooms I would like to return the following       1           BASKET WEAVING   MTWTHF   103/104/105/106/107

Comment: I have added another query with 3rd column added Rooms, Hopefully this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a pivot table when aggregating some value across know intervals. I would recommend using FOR XML PATH if you want one field with the combination of values. The output using pivot would look like:

```
Class ID   Class Name    Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday   Friday...
1          Class 1       1         1          1            0          0
2          Class 2       0         0          0            1          0
```